# Making in-app purchases with an google play account different from the device primary account

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

Sorry if the title sound confusing. I hope that I can explain better here.
We know that each device can have multiple google account of which the first created google account in the device will be the primary account. In google play app, user can actually select different google account to sign in to Google Play store on the device.

If for example, the device primary account is myprimary@gmail.com and the user sign in to Google Play app with "anotheraccount@gmail.com". The user then made an in-app purchase. The question is, will the user still be able to received the purchased item?

Does anyone has any experience?

Thank you very much.

**Update and edited**

Have also submitted the question to Google Play support. Below is the reply.

*"Thanks for contacting Google. I see that you have some questions about purchasing through the Google Play Store. I am more than happy to answer this question for you. In the question above, if a user were signed into a different account than the primary account on the device, then the account signed into would be the account that was billed for the transaction and it would be the only account with access to the application or in app content that was purchased. I hope that answers your question. If you have any other questions or input, please let me know and I'm happy to help."*

So I guess if the app is signed in with the Device primary account while the purchase is made with another account, the item will not be received. Probably this is the reason why there are many complains on the purchased in-app item not received.

As far as I know, there isn't a way in the android sdk to verify if the device primary account is the same as the one used in the Google play. If anyone has an idea how to verify these 2 accounts, please do share the code.

Comment: +1, but I'm a bit confused: Your original question is _will the user still be able to received the purchased item?_, that you already have answered with Google support's response. Why not write that as an(the) answer and close this question (or leave it open for a few days)? The last point after your edit, _If anyone has an idea how to verify these 2 accounts, please do share the code._ is a complete different question. Write it as a new one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So accordingly to the reply from Google Play support team. The answer to "will the user still be able to received the purchased item?" is clearly a no if the device primary account and the Google Play account is different from each other.