# Manage Multiple Subscriptions for single item for multiple users

Tags: android, google-play

The current Google Play Music app is able to manage subscriptions for multiple users. It is able to switch the user on Google Play and use subscription for them. Is there a known API of telling google play which account to use for subscription/in-app purchase? I want to managed multiple subscriptions that have same Product ID on Google Play but for multiple accounts on same device.

Answer (score 0):

According to a reply by GooglePlay support to a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16643831/making-in-app-purchases-with-an-google-play-account-different-from-the-device-pr), inapp purchases will be available only to the account that was signed in at the time of transaction.