# Restore In-app purchase details

Tags: android, in-app-billing, subscription, google-account

I am implementing subscription in my application.

In a device it has 2 Google accounts(mail1 & mail2). I have purchased a subscription(for my app from Google play store) with mail2 but when I try to restore, it says I don't have any purchase. But if I delete mail1 then I am able to restore purchase.

Can I programmatically know how many Google accounts are registered in a device and which id is used to buy subscription. I am stuck. Please somebody guide me.

Comment: Seems duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16871115/restore-transaction-inapp-purchase-android Basically you need not restore a purchases, instead get purchases for the logged in user

Comment: That is the problem. There are two Google id registered with device. I want to get details of 2nd user but it always retrieves the details related to 1st user. Is there a way to know how many id's are registered and which has purchase details?

Comment: You can use Android's AccountManager to get list of accounts but I guess you can get purchase information only for the logged in primary account. Also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16643831/making-in-app-purchases-with-an-google-play-account-different-from-the-device-pr

Comment: I have solved this. check this link  [https://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/issues/detail?id=76](https://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/issues/detail?id=76)

Comment: What did you do? Would be good if you can add it as an answer to help others.

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple Google accounts signed-in, in that case if you try to get purchase details or subscribe any app:

1> it will take the id which is used while downloading the app from play store.

If the id used to download the app is deleted in that case:

2> it will take the id which is your primary id(i.e. in account list the id which is at topmost position).

for reference please check the link https://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/issues/detail?id=76.